# implementing bold button for wpf richtextbox... selection disappears after applying bold

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have RichTextBox from the Windows WPF library, and I'm trying to make it so I can select text in the richtextbox and click a bold button. as soon as I click the bold button the selected text should remain except what's in the section turns bold, and when i click the bold button again the bold should disappear and the selection should remain unchanged.

Now for what I observe, I click block and the selection disappears.  Here's my code to show tht:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Name="Bold" Content="Bold" Click="Bold_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox1" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
namespace WpfApp2 {    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            RichTextBox1.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("Select this text with a mouse click-and-drag, " 
                                                       + "then click bold button, and observe that "
                                                       + "selection highlight disappears");
        }
        private bool SelectionIsBold() {
            var weight = RichTextBox1.Selection.GetPropertyValue(FontWeightProperty);
            var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var SelectionIsBold = weight != unset && (FontWeight)weight == FontWeights.Bold;
            return SelectionIsBold;
        }
        private void Bold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (RichTextBox1.Selection.IsEmpty) return;
            var textRange = RichTextBox1.Selection;
            var len = RichTextBox1.Selection.Text.Length;
            var startpos = RichTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0);
            var endpos = RichTextBox1.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(len);  //GetPoint(start, len);
            if (SelectionIsBold())
                RichTextBox1.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
            else
                RichTextBox1.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

            // ==>> DOESN"T WORK: Attempt to Reselect Text After ApplyPropertyValue because it unhighlights the selection...
            RichTextBox1.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            RichTextBox1.Selection.Select(startpos, endpos);
        }
    } // class
} // namespace
```

Comment: If my answer worked for you please mark it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is not that the selection is being removed.  When the user clicks on the button the RichTextBox loses focus so the selection highlight appears to go away.  You don't need to worry about re-calculating the selection, just call Focus().

```
private void Bold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (RichTextBox1.Selection.IsEmpty) return;
    if (SelectionIsBold())
        RichTextBox1.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
    else
        RichTextBox1.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

    // The selection brush obviously isn't required but i kept it to make it obvious it is working.
    RichTextBox1.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    RichTextBox1.Focus(); // Return focus to the Text Box after the button click
}
```